# Why is the right side running out of the browser size?

Tags: html, css, positioning, sizing

The right side of the container runs out of the browser and a scroll-bar shows up.

How can i adjust to be just fit in the browser?
And the bottom does not reach the bottom of the browser... Any idea?

```
.container {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute; 
}
```

Comment: Well, you have set margins? Is this intentional? Remove margins, if you want to remove scrollbar.

Comment: I think that more code is needed here... 
That `margin-left` is making the horizontal scroll bar appearance...

Comment: removed margins, but still there the scroll-bar, and still running out of the browser

Comment: you should remove margin-left  instead use left:0px;

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2sxkxx0r/ @vinya, is this what you need? Notice usage of box-sizing (so border is counted as a part of div width/height)

Answer (score 1):

You have set `min-width: 100%` AND `margin-left: 200px` which ends up in a total of 100% + 200px, which ends with a horisontal scrollbar.

If you WANT the margin, AND the size to be the rest of the size of the window, you can do this: `max-width: calc(100% -200px);` and just keep the rest the same.

Only works in relatively new browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `min-width: calc(100% - 202px);` to include the margin and borders you defined in the width.

For height, make sure all parent elements have defined heights, which can also mean you have to add `body, html: height: 100%;` . In this case also add `box-sizing: border-box;`, but then the width setting above should be `min-width: calc(100% - 200px);`,  since border-box already includes the border in the width.

Answer (score 1):

if You Use border with width:100% then you have to use **box-sizing:border-box;**

```
position: absolute;
top: 60px;
left:0px;
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
border: 1px solid #ffffff;
background:red;
box-sizing:border-box;
```